# show that the product of infinite cyclic group and finite cyclic group is never cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is how to show that the product of infinite cyclic group and finite cyclic group is never cyclic.
I know how to show that product of two infinite cyclic groups is never cyclic.

Comment: Not true if the finite cyclic group has order one. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: The question is how to show it is never cyclic

Comment: But it is cyclic for $\mathbb Z \times \{0\}$. So therefore you have a counterexample to show that *it is **not** the case that an infinite cyclic group and a finite cyclic group is **never** cyclic.*  One example is all that is needed to show that there actually exists a product as you specify that **is cyclic**.  The negation of "never cyclic", is "at least in one case, it in fact is cyclic."

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement is:

> The product of a infinite cyclic group and a *nontrivial* finite cyclic group is never cyclic.

Indeed, such a product is an infinite group which has nontrivial elements of finite order. This does not happen in an infinite cyclic group.